# Android client won't receive from python server

Tags: python, android, server, client

Hey I just started to learn android and my task was to make an application that sends and receives data from a python server. it sends the data perfectly but I can't make the client receive the data. please go easy on me I'm new here is my code:

Android Code:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @SuppressLint(("Wrong Thread"))
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {
                Log.d("ORI", "1- before connect");
                sock = new Socket(LOCAL_HOST, PORT);
                Log.d("ORI", "2 - after connect" );
                prWriter = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                prWriter.write(msg);
                prWriter.flush();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                sock.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And here is my Python server:

```
import socket

server_sock = socket.socket()
server_sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", 5024))
server_sock.listen(1)

client, addr = server_sock.accept()
print(addr[0])
flag = False
while True:
    try:
        data = client.recv(1024).decode()
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        break

    else:
        if not flag:
            if data == '':
                pass
            print(data)
            try:
                client.send("K".encode())
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            else:
                print("OK")
                flag = True



server_sock.close()
```

Comment: you did not posted any error or exception trace of your problem

Comment: I forgot to mention it shows an error in   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream())); its says the socket is closed.

Comment: and what is the error post full error trace from logcat

Comment: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Comment: you need to update your questions so that everybody can see error log and suggest you a solution in comments its not understandable and reading friendly

Comment: Notwithstanding the slightly bizarre server implementation, it looks as though the only way that the server could explicitly close the socket is if/when an exception is raised during *recv()* and if that happens you have your own message (*print(str(e))*). I haven't done any Java socket work for a while but just wondering if *prWriter.close();* might close the underlying socket. Just for test purposes you could remove that line

Comment: It does I deleted it and it doesn't show the error but doesn't seem to receive either , I will edit again the question.

Comment: There are numerous issues with your server implementation. In particular, your use of *recv()* is highly dubious for two reasons. 1) What happens if/when the client sends more than 1K bytes? 2) What happens if client sends fewer than 1K bytes but not all are received with one *recv()* invocation? You have to have a strategy/protocol that allows the server to "know" when all data have been received. Also, how does the server "know" when all/any clients have finished sending data to it?

Comment: `response.append(line);` That should be: `response.append(line).append("\n");` (Let your server send several lines at once to see why.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Your client tries to read a line using `.readLine()`.

But.. is your server sending a line? Your server sends:

```
 client.send("K".encode())
```

(That is only one character. Why not a big sentence?)

But anyhow it is only a line when the string ends with `\n`.

So change to:

```
 client.send("Hello World\n".encode())
```

Comment: I see now it is able to receive thank you , but the toast doesn't seem to be working, it doesn't print anything for me on the screen. can you help me with that as well?

Comment: Be glad your Android app does not crash. As you cannot display a Toast in a Thread or in doInBackground(). Implement and use onPostExecute() to display that Toast. For that do not return null  in doInBackground() but that message.

Comment: I'm trying but it says cant resolve to symbol 'response' as if it everything after the try gets deleted

Comment: Not deleted but indeed response is unknow if you lare outside the try block. Well i leave that to you to find a solution. :-). And return a String. Not a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea for a more flexible and reliable socket server in Python.

Reading from a socket can be challenging if you can't be certain just how much data to read. If one assumes, for example, that no messages will ever be longer than 1K then you might be tempted to *recv(1024)* but that's not reliable. To be specific, a client could send 800 bytes but the server might "see" fewer bytes with one call to recv().

So, what you need is a protocol that enables to server to know precisely how much data to expect.

One way to do this is to use a fixed length preamble to the message. We can utilise the pack/unpack functions (from the struct module) to build network independent integers which are sent before the actual message. The server knows to expect that preamble (which is of fixed length) and by unpacking that value can perform a recv() for a precise number of bytes.

The following example makes use of this paradigm by implementing an **echo** process whereby the server runs in its own thread, the client sends a message and the server immediately replies with whatever it received in the first place. In this example, the client ends with a "kill switch".

I'm probably opening myself up to all sorts of criticism but here goes anyway:

```
import socket
import threading
from struct import pack, unpack

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 7070
FORMAT = ('!Q', 8)
MSG = '''The Owl and the Pussy-cat went to sea 
   In a beautiful pea-green boat, 
They took some honey, and plenty of money, 
   Wrapped up in a five-pound note. 
The Owl looked up to the stars above, 
   And sang to a small guitar, 
"O lovely Pussy! O Pussy, my love, 
    What a beautiful Pussy you are, 
         You are, 
         You are! 
What a beautiful Pussy you are!"'''


def sendbuffer(s, b):
    buffer = pack(FORMAT[0], len(b)) + b
    offset = 0
    while offset < len(buffer):
        offset += s.send(buffer[offset:])


def recvbuffer(s):
    p = s.recv(FORMAT[1], socket.MSG_WAITALL)
    n = unpack(FORMAT[0], p)[0]
    return None if n == 0 else s.recv(n, socket.MSG_WAITALL)


def server():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen()
        conn, _ = s.accept()
        with conn:
            while (data := recvbuffer(conn)):
                sendbuffer(conn, data)


def client(msg):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))
        sendbuffer(s, msg.encode())
        data = recvbuffer(s)
        print(data.decode())
        sendbuffer(s, b'') # kill switch


def main():
    threading.Thread(target=server).start()
    client(MSG)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

N.B. This has been tested on macOS and may not work as expected on Windows