# Error while reading image received from socket

Tags: python, java, android-studio, sockets, tcp

I have an android app that sends an image from gallery to a Python server via sockets using DataOutputStream to write to the socket in the client app. The image is loaded from external storage directory and buffered before being sent. The image is received by the server and written to disk memory. When I try to open the image it gives me: "Fatal Error reading the image file. Not a PNG". However the image occupies an actual image size of 430 KiB. When I print the data being received it gives me something that looks like a raw image:

```
b'\x97\xa7p\xc0\x04\xfbv\xf6\\\xed\x8a\xe9^\xbf\xa4p9\xae\x8eu:N\xb5\x8e\xcc\x06\xa6\xf1\tyL\xf3.^W\xb5RR\xd3)\x7fS\xf3\x8f\x1b\xc6\xf8\xa7\x9b\xf5\xb8\xc3f\xa9\xdf\xa1\xbd\xaa\xbeS\xbc\x84zt\xedT\xbfn|I\xfb\x0e\xfb\xae6\x18sS\x9b\x9e\xd8\xff\xc4>\xaf\xeb\xba\xbe>{\xe2\x87~\xe8\x87~\xe8\x87~\xe8\x87~\xe8\x87~\xe8\x87~\xe8\x87~\xe8\x87~\xe8\x87~\xe8\x87~\xe8\x87\xfe\xbf\xa4\xff\x07\xe5\x9f\xdc\xd5\xe2d\xc5\xcb\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
b''
```

The text is longer but I cut it down..

The client code that loads the image from directory and writes to socket:

```
class send extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    Socket s; //Socket Variable

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            s = new Socket("192.168.0.14", 9999);
            String image = getLatestFilefromDir("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM");
            File file = new File(image);
            try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                 DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream())) {
                 dos.writeLong(file.length());
                int val;
                while ((val = is.read()) != -1) {
                    dos.write(val);
                }
                dos.flush();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
}


private String getLatestFilefromDir(String dirPath){
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }

File lastModifiedFile = files[0];
for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < files[i].lastModified()) {
        lastModifiedFile = files[i];
    }
}
return lastModifiedFile.toString();
```

}

Python server:

```
#Imports modules

    import socket
    import datetime
    
    date_string = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")
    listensocket = socket.socket()
    listenPort = 9999
    numberOfConnections=1
    
    
    
    thisIp = socket.gethostname()
    listensocket.bind(('', listenPort))
    
    listensocket.listen(numberOfConnections)
    print("Started Listening")
    
    (clientsocket, address) = listensocket.accept()
    print("Connected")
    
    fname = "/home/pi/Desktop/Images/"+date_string+".PNG"
    
    f = open(fname, 'wb')
    datain = 1
    
    
    while datain:
        datain = clientsocket.recv(100000000)
        print(datain)
        bytearray(f.write(datain)) 
    
    f.close()
    listensocket.close()
```

Comment: Your python code contains some nonsensical statements like `datain = clientsocket.recv(100000000)` and `bytearray(f.write(datain))`. But the most important problem is that your python protocol doesn't math your Java protocol. Your Java code first writes out the length of data to follow as a 64-bit big-endian integer. Your python makes no attempt to read in this 64-bit integer and treats these 8 bytes as part of the image file.

Comment: that would be from the dos.writeLong. But how can I write the binary as a Long type in python?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk makes excellent points. In your Python server you might end up with a viable image file if you simply skip the first 8 bytes. Even better, read those 8 bytes and interpret them as an integer value (being aware of endianness). You can then invoke recv() with an explicit length with the addition of socket.MSG_WAITALL in which case you won't need a loop

Comment: @JohnJones take a look at the pack and unpack functions available in the struct module. You could also review an Answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69852606/android-client-wont-receive-from-python-server/69853509#69853509)

Comment: The comments made so far does put me on the right track. I know for sure that it has to do with the Long type image being sent to the server. But I can't figure out how to read it. Additionally, if i could add the flexible strategy to read different image sizes would be helpful, not just to me. I am a beginner trying to learn, is there any example on how to achieve the result expected? It doesn't look easy to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer may not be robust but does demonstrate a mechanism for efficiently transferring files from a Java application to a Python server. Certain paths are hard-coded for demonstration purposes. Also note that this  may not be appropriate if the file being transferred is very large due to the fact that the entire file contents will be held in memory on the server side before writing to the target file. Obviously that can be accounted for with more elaborate code.

Here's the Java client:

```
package com.aprk;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class GetImage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 7070);
            File image = new File("/Volumes/G-DRIVE Thunderbolt 3/Pictures/rgb_colour_wheel.png");
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(image));
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            bos.write(nio(image.length()));
            byte[] buff = new byte[4096];
            int n;
            while ((n = bis.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) > 0) {
                bos.write(buff, 0, n);
            }
            bos.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GetImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    private static byte[] nio(long n) {
        byte[] v = new byte[8];
        int shift = 56;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            v[i] = (byte)(n>>shift);
            shift -= 8;
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Here's the Python server:

```
import socket
from struct import unpack

HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 7070


def main():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen()
        conn, _ = s.accept()
        with conn:
            p = conn.recv(8, socket.MSG_WAITALL)
            n = unpack('!Q', p)[0]
            with open('/tmp/image.png', 'wb') as image:
                while n > 0:
                    data = conn.recv(n)
                    image.write(data)
                    n -= len(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It is a very clear example that also works. However, is there a way to send the image in real time?

Comment: @JohnJones You'll need to explain more about what you want to achieve

Comment: Not necessarily real-time, but write without waiting, currently there's a delay due to the chunks of data being sent, until the file is completely written

Comment: I have re-written my Answer to demonstrate how one could reduce the impact on memory on the server side by receiving whatever's available on the socket. On the client side I now use a BufferedOutputStream. Unfortunately, that class doesn't support writeLong so there's a new private method to deal with that.